# return opposite Boolean value in one line

Tags: javascript, jquery

Common Javascript knowledge (or any programming language really) tells us that using `!variable` will equal the opposite value when it's Boolean (or converted to Boolean in a conditional, etc).

### I have this Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var addEvent = function (element, myEvent, fnc) {
        return ((element.attachEvent) ? element.attachEvent('on' + myEvent, fnc) : element.addEventListener(myEvent, fnc, false));
    };
    var openBar = false;
    addEvent(document.getElementById('toggle'), 'click', function (event) {
        var toggler = event.currentTarget,
            barWrap = document.getElementById('left-wrap'),
            newSize = (!openBar) ? 20 : 0;
        $(barWrap).animate({
            width: (newSize / 100 * window.innerWidth)
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 300,
            step: function (now) {
                toggler.style.right = now + 'px';
                //barWrap.outerWidth = now;
                document.body.style.marginRight = now + 'px';
            },
            complete: function () {
                newSize = (newSize === 20) ? '20%' : '0%';
                document.body.style.marginRight = newSize;
                toggler.style.right = newSize;
                barWrap.style.width = newSize;
            }
        });
        return !openBar;
    });
});
```

...that I threw into [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3R5qe/)...which will show it open the toggle bar but not close it...with a lot of fluffy HTML and CSS too prettify it for y'all.

Now, why on earth does the 3rd to last line NOT return the opposite value as it should?  I have successfully used the following:

```
return openBar = !openBar;
```

but for some reason browsers and JSfiddle and JShint like to get mad when I do because they expect a conditional or value instead of assignment.  But they don't fail to load.  I also know I can use:

```
openBar = !openBar;
return openBar;
```

or even

```
openBar = !openBar;
return;
```

but I like to minimize everywhere I can and really just want to understand why this fundamentally is failing to work for me so I can correct it in the future.

Is this in anyway incompatible with another browser (using Chrome 30 and Firefox 25) or possibly going to error out somewhere I'm not anticipating?

Or is it more of an inconvenience/warning that I can ignore (like those things telling me to use === instead of == when comparing 0 when I know the result can only be a number)?

Comment: `openbar` is not being modified when you do `return !openbar`. Behavior makes sense.

Comment: Even though it's awkward - it's still syntactically correct: http://jsfiddle.net/JHTct/ and **does** work

Comment: When I use !(openBar) in a separate part of the code it will alter the value correctly without using an assignment

Comment: Returning an assignment is fine, on JSHint you can just use `boss:true` and will get rid of the warning.

Comment: my focus isn't how to fix the error on fiddle or jshint, sorry if that was unclear.  I want to understand why `return !openBar` (or even `return !(openBar)` fail to assign the negation as I expect

Comment: Because there's no assignment, that's it.

Comment: @Deryck: warning from *what*? I don't see any warnings from JS engine at my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/JHTct/

Comment: @zerkms click `JSHint` warning appears. Boom, no warnings http://jsfiddle.net/JHTct/1/

Comment: @zerkms click the "JSHint" button on top and hover on the red dot next to that line.  Like I said, it's not functionally impairing that I can see but what I'm using it for needs to be backwards compatible pretty far.

Comment: @elclanrs: I see now. Probably the question should state more clearly that it's about jshint specifically

Comment: @Deryck: What you want to do is common, you can return the last expression of every function and your program will most likely still work.

Comment: "backwards compatible pretty far" --- the `return foo = bar;` code is compatible with anything. It's a trivial language construct

Comment: @zerkms and elclanrs thanks I got it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you have to explicitly re-assign your original `openBar` variable for it to work. I'm interested in seeing an example of what makes you think otherwise. I made this small modification and removed the return:

```
newSize = (openBar = !openBar) ? 20 : 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a9NPG/1/ (although I read that you're not really interested in it.)

Comment: Actually I'm very interested and will be using that lol thank you.  And the thing that made me question this whole thing is that using `!(openBar);` would negate AND set the variable to the new value but of course now...it's not.  Which makes me think I did something else but can't remember.  What's new.

Comment: So I edited that one a little bit. I looked back and realised that I needed to encapsulate the openBar assignment in parentheses. It technically works the other way (re-assigning openBar to 20 or 0) since the ternary will read a 0 value the same as false, but we shouldn't be so loose with our typing.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.reverse()` is a nice little fella:

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/olUVEke/1/edit)**

```
$(function () {

    var $toggler = $('#toggle'),
        $barWrap = $('#left-wrap'),
        $doc     = $('body'),
        newSize  = ['0', '20'];

    $toggler.on('click', function(){
        var winW = window.innerWidth,
            perc = newSize.reverse()[0],
            px   = perc / 100 * winW; 
        console.log( px );
        $barWrap.animate({   width : px });
        $toggler.animate({   right : px });
        $('body').animate({ marginRight: px }); 
    }); 

});
```

Comment: I appreciate the time you put into creating this but I actually went FROM this to what I have now lol.  Pure JS is a bit faster than jQuery (even though I have to use it for the animation itself).  I'm also using pure JS to help learn it better instead of straight jQuery like I have been for so long.  Thank you though this does work nicely.  +1